# Angular2 TypeScript interface array not working

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, interface

I am writing an Angular2 application. I want to display messages using an interface and an array containing all the messages. Here is the interesting part of my TypeScript component:

```
export class ChatComponent
{
  messages: message[];
  constructor()
  {
    this.messages.push({from: 'me', time: new Date().getTime(), type: 'text', value: 'Hallo Welt!', sent: new Date().getTime(), delivered: 0, read: 0});
  }
}

interface message
{
  from: string;
  time: number;
  type: string;
  value: string;
  sent: number;
  delivered: number;
  read: number;
}
```

As you can see from TypeScript side of things everything looks alright (I guess). Displaying stuff in the template worked fine, in this case I am using the following:

```
<div class = "message" *ngFor = "let message of messages">
  <div>{{message.value}}</div>
  <div>{{message.time}}</div>
</div>
```

When just using an array and filling it with objects this setup is working fine. But as soon as I use the interface `message` and the array I get

```
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: this.messages is undefined
```

I feel like it's some stupid mistake or misunderstanding, but couldn't find anything useful. Why should `this.messages` be undefined?

Comment: "But as soon as I use the interface message and the array I get" how do you use "interface messages" to get this error?

Comment: Well, to be honest I don't know any other way to express it? Sorry, I am new to TypeScript...

Comment: It would be nice if one could tell why a question is getting a downvote. I need information to get better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you are not initializing the messages array. You are not giving the field a value before setting it. As your code stands right now, the constructor will throw an error because you are calling `this.messages.push` but `this.messages` is undefined because you did not give it a value. You can use the following to fix it:

```
export class ChatComponent
{
  messages: message[];
  constructor()
  {
    this.messages = [];
    this.messages.push({from: 'me', time: new Date().getTime(), type: 'text', value: 'Hallo Welt!', sent: new Date().getTime(), delivered: 0, read: 0});
  }
}
```

Or even better:

```
export class ChatComponent
{
  messages: message[];
  constructor()
  {
    this.messages = [{from: 'me', time: new Date().getTime(), type: 'text', value: 'Hallo Welt!', sent: new Date().getTime(), delivered: 0, read: 0}];
  }
}
```